# Did the Egyptians use whips on the Hebrew slaves? Why do we assume so?

Tags: history, parshanut-torah-comment, chinuch-education, egypt

It seems like every image I've ever seen drawn (or acted) of the Jews' slavery in Egypt involves them being *whipped* by Egyptians. The Torah says that the Jewish foremen were *stricken* as their underlings weren't meeting the quota, but where did everyone seem to take for granted that whips came into the picture per se? Are there Jewish textual sources? Some influential painting perhaps? Archaeological or parallel historic sources?

Comment: I'll put my money on Maxwell House

Comment: Good to the last "crop" :(

Answer (score 6):

We see when Moshe went out he saw the Mitzri hitting and whipping a Jew (Malkeihu V'Rodehu)

See [Rashi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=22)

see translation of Malkehu = lashing [here](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15559&p=3&showrashi=true)

Comment: Fascinating. Rashi (it says quoting Shemos Rabba, I haven't looked it up) starts by saying "malkehu v'rodehu" -- whipping and abusing him. But concludes with "makehu v'rodehu" -- striking and abusing him. Do we then assume the terms are meant as synonyms? ... Though devil's advocate, this midrash says the whipping wasn't "build faster, slave!", but rather, "I'm putting you in your place -- I can do whatever I want with my wife and you can't stop me."

Answer (score 0):

We also see when the officers of Bnei Ysrael [were beaten](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0205.htm#14), Sefer Mishneh Kesef, ([Matzref LeKesef to Shemos 5:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_9459_148.pdf)) comments Vayuku:

> :ויכו. הוא  מין ההכאה הנהונ בארץ ההיא, והוא להפילו לארץ ולהכותו **בשוטים**

Comment: "Shutim" are sticks, not whips, as far as I know.

Comment: שוט: whip or scourge. See: http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_49975_705.pdf